# Firebase Search Can't Show Results

Tags: java, android

I want to make search data on my app based on Firebase. I've followed instructions on internet how to make search Firebase. 
It shows no error, but when I clicked search button, my recycleview is empty, no data showed.

> Here is my code:

```
     btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String searchText = search_cust.getText().toString();
             firebaseCustSearch(searchText);
         }
     });
```

> This is my firebase search method

```
private void firebaseCustSearch(String searchText) {

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = databaseCustomer.orderByChild("custName").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions customerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Customer>()
            .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, Customer.class).build();

    adapter =   new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Customer, CustomerList.ViewHolder>(customerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomerList.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Customer model) {
            holder.setname(model.getCustName());
            holder.setaddress(model.getCustAddress());
            Toast.makeText(CRUDCustomer.this, model.custName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CustomerList.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    listViewCustomer.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewCustomer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

}
```

> ViewHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Customer customer = customerList.get(position);

    holder.textName.setText(customer.getCustName());
    holder.textAddress.setText(customer.getCustAddress());
    holder.textPhone.setText(customer.getCustPhone());

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textName ;
    public TextView textAddress;
    public TextView textPhone ;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view){
        super(view);
        this.textName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cust_name);
        this.textAddress = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cust_address);
        this.textPhone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cust_phone);
    }

    public void setname(String name){

        textName.setText(name);

    }
    public void setaddress(String address){
        textAddress.setText(address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> private void search(String text) {
>           List filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();
>           for (Modelclass s : modelclass) {

```
        if (s.getname.contains(text)) {

            search.add(s);
        }
    }

    //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list
    sampleAdapter.filterList(filterdNames);
}
```

Comment: private void search(String text) {
        List<Modelclass> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Modelclass s : modelclass) {
            if (s.getname.contains(text)) {
                search.add(s);
            }
        }

        //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list
        sampleAdapter.filterList(filterdNames);
    }